# Link SQL Table > MS Access with Date/Time

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have tables linked from SQL Server to MS Access.  The issues is the date on MS Access doesn't display the non value zeros exam: in SQL 01/01/2016 in Access 1/1/2016.  In the query I have this set up `RDATE: Left(CStr([RENEWAL_DATE]),**10**)` to eliminate the time, but when the date has less then 10 characters part of the time appears.

What I'm looking for is to clear things up. How can I have MS Access display Date like 01/01/2016 rather than 1/1/2016?

Comment: Dates do not have formats, they are *values* just like decimals and integers. Use whatever functions are available to either truncate the time portion or cast the value to `date` or the equivalent in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever handle dates like strings. No exceptions.

Here you can use:

```
RDATE: DateValue([RENEWAL_DATE])
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

In the query design view you can specify the format that Access will use to display a value in your date column. When you are in the design view of your query, right click the date column, choose properties. There you have the format property.